# Animate Menu Collapsed - Menu Expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('#sidebar');


$('button').click(function() {
  var width = $('#sidebar').width();
  if(width == 100) {
     $('#sidebar').animate({width:"30"});
     menu.classList.toggle("menu-expanded");
  } else {
     $('#sidebar').animate({width:"100"});
     menu.classList.toggle("menu-collapsed");
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-expanded{
  width: 100px;
}

#menu-btn {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.menu-collapsed{
  width: 50px;
}
li a{
  font-size: 20px;
}
.menu-collapsed li a{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul id="sidebar" class="menu-expanded">
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ex, voluptatum error itaque provident totam ratione, quaerat reprehenderit accusantium omnis veniam voluptatibus fugiat ducimus, eos, consequuntur perferendis fugit adipisci dolores.
  </div>
</div>

<button id="menu-btn">MENU</button>
```

Soy nueva usando JavaScript, y lo que deseo es que al momento de dar click en el boton, el menu COLLAPSE y tenga un ancho distinto y su contenido tambien cambien sus propiedades (en este caso cambiar el tamaño de fuente), estoy haciendolo con javaScrip, cuando presiono el boton por primera vez el contenido cambia su tamaño, pero cuando lo presiono por segunda vez para EXPANDIR el menu, el contenido no recupera sus propedades. Lo deseo hacer con la propiedad ANIMATE por que no se ve muy brusco el cambio de propiedades, les dejo el codigo para que puedan ayudar; GRACIAS!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de lo que te está pasando te está ocurriendo en la función toggle('mi-clase-css') de jQuery. Esa función lo que hace es, que dado el nombre de una clase (en el ejemplo, "mi-clase-css"), la pondrá si no existe y la quitará si ya existe, pero siempre se refiere a una misma clase CSS.

Si nos fijamos en tu código, en el if-else estás teniendo 2 clases distintas en el toggle, por lo tanto, no te va a funcionar como estás esperando.

Te recomendaría que cambies el nombre de la clase para que no represente dos estados distintos de tu menú (expanded y collapsed), al menos, para la funcionalidad que estás comentando. En su lugar, una clase "menu-opened" sería más claro, y tu toggle quedaría como `toggle('menu-opened')`. De esta forma, si la clase está, el menú está "colapsado" y con la fuente pequeña, y cuando la clase exista, el menú crecerá a toda su anchura y la fuente será mayor. Además, tu código se podría simplificar muchísimo, como verás después en el ejemplo adjunto.

Por otro lado, como recomendación complementaria, esa animación que se está haciendo en código con jQuery, podrías hacerla igualmente por CSS, de modo que todo lo que tiene que ver con estilos está codificado en la hoja de estilos, la separación del código es más clara y mantenible, y el código JavaScript se reduce, siendo más fácil luego hacer tests de tu código. Obviamente quizás esto sea un ejercicio en el que estás sólo practicando, pero que comprendas que esa separación es una práctica habitual, sí que es recomendable conocerlo.

Te dejo a continuación el ejemplo completo y con la animación. He dejado comentarios aclarando algunas líneas y respetando la funcionalidad planteada en la pregunta original. Si alguien tiene dudas, podemos utilizar los comentarios. Espero que la respuesta pueda ser de ayuda.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('#sidebar');

$('button').click(function() {
  menu.classList.toggle("menu-collapsed");
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-btn {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
.main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.menu {  /* Por defecto, el menú estará abierto (100px) */
  width: 100px;
  /* La propiedad CSS de transition permite aplicar animaciones eficientemente, de modo que aprovechamos eso y le decimos que vamos a cambiar el "width" del menú, con una duración de 350 milisegundos. "ease-in-out" es la forma en la que se anima (animation curve por si quieres buscar más sobre ello) */
  transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;  
}
.menu.menu-collapsed {
  width: 30px;  /* Cuando exista la clase menu-collapsed, se reducirá a 30px */
}
li a {  /* Por defecto, al estar el menú abierto, la fuente será de 20px. También con transition le decimos que vamos a animar el tamaño de la tipografía para darle una animación más suave igual que antes */
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: font 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-collapsed li a {
  font-size: 15px;  /* Cuando la función toggle() añada la clase "menu-collapsed", el tamaño de la fuente cambiará a 15px */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul id="sidebar" class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">This is link</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="main">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus ex, voluptatum error itaque provident totam ratione, quaerat reprehenderit accusantium omnis veniam voluptatibus fugiat ducimus, eos, consequuntur perferendis fugit adipisci dolores.
  </div>
</div>

<button id="menu-btn">MENU</button>
```

Comment: Dejo también el fiddle por si alguien le sirve de ayuda: https://jsfiddle.net/semagarcia/a89krvtc/1/

Comment: Gracias infinitas Sema

Comment: Un placer ayudar :)